# Для чего нужна Factory в ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, viewmodel

Подскажите пожалуйста только изучаю андроид. Я так понял, если говорить проще ViewModel нужна, что бы восстановить инфу во время работы с приложением к примеру во время поворота экрана, но что делает Factory который мы расширяем из extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory?

Comment: о какой конкретно ViewModel идет речь. Данный класс используется во множестве совершенно разных технологий

Comment: Обычный ViewModel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим вы хотите передать во ViewModel какой-то аргумент, например, строку. С помощью обычного способа через конструктор у вас не получится, так как вы должны получать ViewModel вот так.

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Чтобы передать аргумент нужно использовать фабрику. Например, вот так. Создаем экземпляр фабрики и через конструктор передаем наше значение name.

```
 public class ModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

   private String name;

   public ModelFactory(String name) {
       super();
       this.name = name;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
       if (modelClass == MyViewModel.class) {
           return (T) new MyViewModel(name);
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

Теперь мы можем создать ViewModel и передать в нее параметр. Делается это вот так

```
MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new ModelFactory("Android")).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Да. Сейчас синтаксис вызова поменялся: `ViewModelProvider(this, ModelFactory("Android")).get(MyViewModel::class.java)`.